# Update EKS cluster Jobs using serverless lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

We are trying to update EKS cluster Jobs using serverless lambda function using @kubernetes/client-node npm package.

This serverless lamba function is using kubeconfig file to authenticate with EKS cluster. Both lambda and EKS cluster are in same VPC and we have provided admin permission to lambda role. and we are getting this following error:

```
getCredential result :  {
  error: Error: spawnSync aws ENOENT
      at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1107:20)
      at ExecAuth.spawnSync [as execFn] (child_process.js:776:24)
      at ExecAuth.getCredential (/var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:1286:29)
      at ExecAuth.applyAuthentication (/var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:1218:33)
      at KubeConfig.applyAuthorizationHeader (/var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:743:33)
      at KubeConfig.applyOptions (/var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:751:20)
      at KubeConfig.applyToRequest (/var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:474:20)
      at /var/task/_optimize/eks-job-dev-sendTaskToEKS/ecs-task.js:17721:95 {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawnSync aws',
    path: 'aws',
    spawnargs: [
      '--region',
      '<region>',
      'eks',
      'get-token',
      '--cluster-name',
      '<cluster-name>'
    ]
  },
  status: null,
  signal: null,
  output: null,
  pid: 23,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

We think that lambda is not able to execute aws command.

Here is the kubeconfig sample format

```
export const kubeconfig = {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "clusters": [
      {
        "cluster": {
          "certificate-authority-data": "sample",
          "server": "server-url"
        },
        "name": "cluster name"
      }
    ],
    "contexts": [
      {
        "context": {
          "cluster": "sample",
          "user": "sample"
        },
        "name": "sample"
      }
    ],
    "current-context": "sample",
    "kind": "Config",
    "preferences": {},
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "sample",
        "user": {
          "exec": {
            "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1",
            "args": [
              "--region",
              "<region>",
              "eks",
              "get-token",
              "--cluster-name",
              "cluster name"
            ],
            "command": "aws"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

And this works fine locally.